# What is the difference between render :object and :collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it

- @cart have to put in :object ?
- @cart.item have to put in : collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `:collection` will run the partial once for every item in the array.  While you're in the partial, the name of the object will be the name of the partial. So if you have:

```
<%= render :partial => 'cart', :collection => @carts %>
```

Then in your partial (_cart.html.erb, for example) you can use the `cart` object:

```
Cart Name: <%= cart.name %>
```

Here's a link to the documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html